# Параметры модели попадают через строку браузера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть методы `Index` контроллера `files`.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UploadModel ResultModel)
    {
        if (ResultModel.FileId != null)
        {
            ViewBag.UploadResutl = "File Uploaded Successful!";
            ViewBag.UploadLink = $"File Link :: {ResultModel.FileId}";
            ViewBag.UploadPassword = $"File Password :: {ResultModel.Password}";
        }
        else
            ViewBag.UploadResutl = ResultModel.Result;
        return View();
    }
```

Поля `UploadModel`  это приватные данные которые отображаются на `View` после успешной загрузки файла и переадресации :

Представление :

```
<div> 
    <h3>Выберите файл для загрузки</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("upload", "files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="upload" value="Открыть" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
    }
</div>
```

Загрузка файла :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("Index", ResultModel);
}
```

Однако, кроме того они отображаются в строке браузера и Истории что уже не хорошо. Как передать в `Index` модель что бы она не отображалась в строке браузера ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте POST запрос

Comment: У тебя должно быть 2 метода, GET и POST, на Get ты показываешь форму для аплоада, на метод POST отправляешь форму с файлами и тогда не будет этих данных в строке

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk имеете в виду 2 метода `Index` - один GET без и второй POST с пераметром ?

Comment: через сессию или TempData

Comment: @Сергей да, 2 метода

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Всегда попадает на GET, можно пример ?

Comment: @Сергей приведите пример как вы отправляете данные

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Дополнил вопрос отправкой данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Модель**

```
public class UploadViewModel
{
    public string UploadResult {get;set;}
    public string UploadLink {get;set;}
    public string UploadPassword {get;set;}
    public HttpFilePostedBase File {get;set;}
    public bool HasUploaded {get;set;}
}
```

По `GET` запросу загружаем страницу:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new UploadViewModel());
}
```

**View**

```
@model UploadViewModel

<div> 
    <h3>Выберите файл для загрузки</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.File)" value="Открыть" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
    }
</div>

@if (model.HasUploaded)
{
    <div>@model.UploadResult</div>
    <div>Link: @model.UploadLink</div>
    <div>Password: @model.UploadPassword</div>
}
```

`POST` метод

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UploadViewModel model)
{
    if (model.File != null)
    {
        // upload file


        model.UploadResult = .....
    }

    return View(model)
}
```